# ContextMenuStrip FindForm is null

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have a `ContextMenuStrip` on a `DataGridView`.  After realizing that calling `cm.FindForm()` results in null, I added the context menu to the grid's `ContextMenuStrip` property, but that doesn't help.

Is there some other setting that I'm missing so that the context menu's `FindForm()` will return the form?

**Note**: I added the context menu via the visual studio designer by dragging it to the form.  Also the main menu (a `MenuStrip`) doesn't show this behavior, its `FindForm()` returns the form properly.

**Edit**: For Hans (why I do things the way I do)

I used to have all code in one long Form1.cs, but that is obviously hard to maintain.  I found that separating all code into a framework that is a separate class for each component, that then references the other classes as needed by injection easier to maintain and follow.

For those components that are not controls, I pass the form the component belongs into the constructor, but for those components that are controls, I found the `FindForm()` method to be a shortcut.  The base class of the framework uses the `FindForm()`.  **Therefore each component has access to the form via a Form property.**

Now I'm finding that the context menu control is not getting, as said, its Parent control set, and therefore `FindForm()` isn't working.

Comment: ContextMenuStrip behaves like a Component, easy to see in the designer.  It's Parent property is null.  Which means that nobody "owns" it and that FindForm() can't do its job.  It isn't obvious why you need this so hard to suggest an alternative.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform.aspx ...section #remarks. i think it explains the behavior. you assign contextmenustrip to a control, but it's still like a "standalone" component, like @HansPassant said.

Comment: @HansPassant Edited post to answer your question.

Comment: You are working around a problem induced by not passing enough information to the constructors of these classes.  Google "dependency injection" to find a general solution to this kind of design issue.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans for the obvious, but the question isn't about my design problems, but why the context menu's FindForm() is null.